# How does clamp() differ from setting width, max-width, & min-width?

Tags: css, clamp

I recently realized that you can use the CSS function [clamp()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()) in combination with `width` to set a "max width" and "min width". I am wondering what the fundamental difference is when using `width` + `clamp()` over `min-width`, `width`, `max-width`.

In other words, how does this...

```
.item {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 200px;
   min-width: 100px;
}
```

...differ from this...

```
.item {
   width: clamp(100px, 100%, 200px);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am wondering what the fundamental difference is

They are completely different so it's wrong to assume they are the same. I can give you a lot of examples where they behave differently but here is only one that should be enough to demonstrate that they are not the same:

```css
.item1 {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.item2 {
  width: clamp(200px, 100%, 300px);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height:80px;
  margin:10px;
  width:150px;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.container>* {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item2"></div>
</div>
```

In the below, using `min-width` will set a minimum boundary for the shrink effect (you get an overflow) while it's not the case when using `clamp()`

In most of the cases, you may not notice any difference but keep in my mind that they are indeed different.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong or missing something but setting `display: block` on `.container` (need also `height:100%` on items or you won't see them) the items will both correctly overflow, the containing is an effect from flexbox, `clamp` is setting correctly the min value requested if you look via devtools.   
So I guess the point is not really `clamp` per se but *where/how* it is applied right?

Comment: @Gruber I doesn't really matter if it's flexbox or something else. I took the first example I had in mind to show that we don't get the same *final* result which mean both aren't the same. If both were the same (like assumed by the OP) then they should always produce the same result whatever the code configuration. Both can be used in most of the cases to get the same result but we cannot say they are exactly the same.

Comment: you just cheat in your exemple, parent re 150px, so your min is not at the good value, the good behavior is the first... the error is you... not the result, so I dont seee any difference beteen both(when we code with logical and no erreur)

Comment: @Matrix sorry but we are not perfect like you. You code with logical and without error so good for you. *We* make errors so maybe this answer is not for you.

Comment: Waw... this ego stupid response ! :| im shocked...